How to show that MLE of probit regression does not exist due to data separability
Claim
The claim is the is the following:
Assume we have the simple probit model $E(y_i|x_i ) = Φ(α+\beta x_i)$. Now suppose that $y_i = 1$ for all $x_i ≤ 10$ and $y_i = 0$ for all $x_i > 10$. Then $\beta_{ML} = − \infty$.
My guess is that this statement should be correct. What I would like to derive is a formal proof that it's true.
Intuition
There is obviously a data separability problem, which usually means trouble for binary response models. In that particular case the model will try to fit the parameter such that we get probability of $P[y_i=1 | x_i>10] = 0$, once the threshold of $x_i=10$ is reached. Meaning that for larger $x_i$ we will get 0, indicating that $\beta$ must be negative. And optimally as negative as possible (in order to replicate the hard threshold at $x_i=10$).
Simulation in R
# Create sample data
n <- 100
x <- runif(n, 0, 20) # generate random x values between 0 and 20
y <- ifelse(x <= 10, 1, 0) # set y to 1 if x <= 10, otherwise set to 0

# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

# Estimate probit model
probit_model <- glm(y ~ x, data = df, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

# Display model summary
summary(probit_model)

As expected R indicates that there is trouble with the MLE
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

$\beta$ is negative and the standard error explodes. All typical for non-existence of the MLE.
Formal Proof (just the start)
$$
L(\pi) = \prod_{i=1}^{N} \left( \pi^{y_i} \cdot (1-\pi)^{1-y_i} \right)
$$
$$
l(\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( y_i \cdot \log(\pi) + (1-y_i) \cdot \log(1-\pi) \right)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial l(\pi)}{\partial \pi} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( \frac{y_i}{\pi} - \frac{1-y_i}{1-\pi} \right) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial l(\pi)}{\partial \pi} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( \frac{y_i}{F(x_i^T \beta)} - \frac{1-y_i}{1- F(x_i^T \beta)} \right) = 0
$$
Where $ F(x_i^T \beta) = \Phi(\alpha+\beta x_i) $.
And now one should probably somehow exploit the information about the threshold $x_i=10$ of data separability. There are a lot of terms which will simplify to 0 in the score (because $y_i \in \{0, 1\}$) , right? I would guess that it reduces to something like that but I am not sure about it:
$$
\frac{\partial l(\pi)}{\partial \pi} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( \frac{1}{F(x_i^T \beta)} - \frac{1}{1- F(x_i^T \beta)} \right) = 0
$$

Can you give a reference for the statement? I seem to recall having seen it somewhere, but struggle to relocate it. Also, while one does get large negative coefficients, they are not found to be Inf by R, such as -25.94 for set.seed(1)

Furthermore, while I am of course not claiming that such separation is not an issue, convergence does appear to take place, which can be checked by increasing maxit from its default of 25. For the above seed there is convergence after 31 iterations.
